# How can I make a QRCode replication with ZPL II

Tags: qr-code, zebra-printers, thermal-printer, zpl-ii

I have a project to make QRCode replication with Zebra ZD220. I need to scan a QRCode (at PCB) and print it automatically (like a copy).

I tried some tutorials in zebra's portal without success.

Anyone could help me? I'm complete new with ZPL II programming

Comment: what development environment/language are you using? are you able to print using the sample code? if so add the example code that you are using. If you are able to print using the sample code then the printing of the QR code is likely just coming up with a way to wrap the QR code in proper ZPL.

Comment: Perhaps ZPL II is a command system for printers and does not have the ability to read barcodes? Also, ordinary barcode scanners only notify you of decoded text(or binary) data, so you cannot get the parameters needed to create the same barcode image. This question is probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xy-problem). You should focus and rethink your true problem.

Comment: @kunif ZPL is kind of an markup language like HTML

Comment: @Delphi Coder  I think I understand that, but the OP doesn't seem to understand it. After all, the ZPL II and Zebra ZD220 have no hardware or software to read QRCode barcodes. And the project of reading the barcode and printing the same barcode as if copying a document seems to be mistaken for the problem to be solved.